# Show the input[type=file] filename at directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement something like the [bootstrap-file-uploader](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) in pure angular. This bootstrap extension replaces the default file-upload widget with a consistent alternative ([see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scardine/y9quS/7/)).

I'm unable to show the selected filename in another element from the same directive. Tried the following already:

- scope.fileName = files[0].name
- ngModel
- scope.$apply.

The event is fired and value is changed, but the change is not reflected in the interface.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('uploader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>filename: {{ fileName }}</div><input type="file">',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            var file = el.find('input');
            scope.fileName = '?';
            file.bind('change', function(ev) {
                var files = event.target.files;
                scope.fileName = files[0].name;
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.fileName = files[0].filename;
                });
                console.log(files, ev);
            });
        }    
    };
});
```

[UPDATE]

Its working now - `files[0].filename` should be `files[0].name`.

Comment: You've got it - `files[0].name` should be wrapped in the `scope.$apply`.  [Plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/g115Yw0XcEichtd1c5ad?p=preview)

Comment: @rGil: thanks! make it an answer and collect your rep...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was there, just not implemented in `scope.$apply`.

Corrected:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.fileName = files[0].name;
```

Comment: my problem is when i check this in the android browser its returning index of the selected file not filename.  http://jsfiddle.net/scardine/y9quS/7/