# Displaying a selected file from an <input> in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filereader

I have a working example using standard Javascript, but I'd like to make this work more natively with AngularJS.

Specifically, I need to update the span with the filename of the file selected by the user.

Here's what I implemented using native Javascript:

```
<span>
    <input  ng-model="uploadDownloads" type="file" style="visibility:hidden; width: 1px;" id=uploadDownloads name=uploadDownloads onchange="$(this).parent().find('span').html($(this).val().replace('C:\\fakepath\\', ''))"  /> <!-- Chrome security returns 'C:\fakepath\'  -->
    <input  class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="choose file" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();"/> <!-- on button click fire the file click event -->
    <span  class="badge badge-important" ></span>
</span>
```

The filereader function is in angular already :

```
$scope.add = function(valid){
        if(valid){
                $scope.data = 'none';
                var f = document.getElementById('uploadDownloads').files[0];
                var r = new FileReader();
                r.onloadend = function(e){
                    $scope.data = e.target.result;
                    $scope.notPass = false;
                    $modalInstance.close({
                        'data':$scope.data,
                        'fileName':$scope.fileName,
                        'fileExplain':$scope.fileExplain
                    });
                };
            /*activate the onloadend to catch the file*/
                r.readAsBinaryString(f);
        } else {
            $scope.notPass = true;
        }
    };
```

The problem is to activate the onclick and the onchange with Angular instead the JavaScript so that my `<span>` gets updated with the selected filename.

Comment: What's the exact question here? Also, your code isn't very idiomatic of AngularJS. You ought to look into using ng-change and ng-click. Also, if you're modifying the DOM, you ought to consider using a directive.

Comment: i want to make the same thing that here but with angular

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Have you looked at this stackoverflow question and answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Comment: its not the upload that i cant do, its to add the file name to the span

Comment: Have you looked at this article?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213526/show-the-inputtype-file-filename-at-directive-template

Comment: You might also want to look at [this article]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227788/get-source-and-name-of-selected-file-with-angularjs). As I mentioned above, you probably want to do this as a custom directive (that would be the more Angular way to do it)... alternatively, use one of the existing Angularjs modules that has already solved your scenario.

Comment: do you know how to do this in angular : .val().replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '')

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27228395/2305837 (see above). Your question is how to do this in an angular way. The angular way would be to use a directive. If you're not familiar with them, you can find documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. The answer linked to literally shows you how to get what you want the angular way. The part where he shows: `console.log(files[0].name);` has the value you want. As a quick (but not ideal) solution, from within the directive modify the parent scope with that value and bind that to your <span>. Sorry if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: You're just trying to put the filename selected in the span, correct?

Comment: yes, thank you for all the great answers bur still it doesn't work

Comment: ok - perfect, I'm writing an answer right now with a codepen to demonstrate the solution :).

Comment: cant wait for it ! thanks :)

Comment: Ok... answer posted. Let me know if it answers your question by accepting it as the correct answer and upvoting it... otherwise, comment on the answer itself with any specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question builds upon an existing [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227788/get-source-and-name-of-selected-file-with-angularjs/27228395#27228395). Specifically, however, I have modified the code from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27228395/2305837) to accomodate what appears to be the specific question here, which is how do you update a `<span>` to have the filename selected by a user in a way that's idiomatic to angularjs.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jpoveda/pen/dYxPLN) with a working sample.

Here's the relevant part of the html file:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <input ng-model="uploadDownloads" type="file" fd-input file-name="fileName"/> 
    <span class="badge badge-important">Output here: {{fileName}}</span>
</body>
```

What's key here is that you have a custom directive called `fd-input` that has a two-way binding to an attribute it defines called `file-name`. You can pass one of your `$scope` variables into that attribute and the directive will bind the filename to it. Here's the controller and the directive.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('AppController', AppController)
    .directive('fdInput', fdInput);

  function AppController($scope) {
    $scope.fileName = '';
  }

  function fdInput() {
    return {
      scope: {
        fileName: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('change', function(evt) {
          var files = evt.target.files;
          console.log(files[0].name);
          console.log(files[0].size);

          scope.fileName = files[0].name;
          scope.$apply();
        });
      }
    }
  };

})();
```

As mentioned above, the directive is taken directly from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27228395/2305837). I have modified it to add a scope that does a two way binding to a `file-name` attribute:

```
...
return {
  scope: {
    fileName: '='
  },
...
```

I then assign `files[0].name` to the two-way binding:

```
...
scope.fileName = files[0].name;
scope.$apply();
...
```

Checkout the codepen. That should do it. You could just use the parent scope in the directive, but that's not a good idea as it limits you to using this directive once per controller. Also, if you want to list multiple files, you'll have to update this code to return an array of those files instead.

Hope this help.

Comment: ok, so i added it to my html code and my angular controller, and it didnt worked. but when i tried it in some test.html and test.js it worked. i think that it may not work because i use it in a angular-ui modal . it does upload the file , but doesn't show the name, i think for some reason it doesn't triggers the directive.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a different question that strays from the context of this question. My suggestion would be that this answer solves your problem (if the solution is working in isolation), and you should proceed by searching Stackoverflow for a solution to properly sharing your `$scope` with your angular-ui modal. You're almost there! :) If you don't mind, mark this answered so that it doesn't show up as unanswered when the community is searching around for questions to answer. Good luck!

Comment: for what is the :file-name="fileName" in the < input > ?

Comment: Read the directives documentation: (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) - in the directive there's a property `scope` in the returned object that has an object with the property `fileName: '='` - that creates an attribute that supports two-way binding. You pass a `$scope.whatever` property into that attribute, which the directive then binds the results to (`scope.fileName = files[0].name;`)... if you pass `$scope.test` into the `file-name` attribute, the directive binds `files[0].name` to `$scope.test`.  The `scope.$apply()` then triggers a digest cycle so things update in your view.